# All newly created iOS apps will be made available on Mac : mine is not working

Tags: ios, macos, app-store

In AppStore Connect, a new frame appeared a few days ago:

> All newly created and existing compatible iOS apps will be made available on Mac. Your compatible apps will be published on the Mac App Store unless you edit their availability.

So I though I would need to publish a newer version of my app to make it available in macOS, but it's not working.

How can I make my app available on iOS ans Mac ?

Comment: I don't believe that the apps will be visible on Mac until Big Sur is released

Answer (score 1):

In June 2020, this message in App Store Connect said that iOS apps would be made available **on Apple Silicon Macs**.

[image: June message]

Later, this message was modified to drop the qualifier about Apple Silicon Macs.

[image]

At a glance, this would seem to indicate that Apple has decided to allow iOS apps to run in an emulated ARM environment on x86 Macs, but I do not believe this is the case. Developer Relations probably just decided to drop that qualifier because they want more developers to support running on the Apple Silicon Macs.